# Helm upgrade stuck until deleting the data-migration pod

Tags: helm

Can anyone please guide me to run the commands in parallel to automate.

Suppose for example:

I wrote a script to upgrade the helm charts and as soon as the `upgrade` command runs, it gets stuck due to data-migration pod, so we need to delete the data-migration job manually to unblock the `upgrade` command. As soon as I delete the data-migration job manually, the `upgrade` command runs.

In the script I am not able to run the `delete` command because the `upgrade` command must complete before I can run anything else.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear in which language you write the script. If it's shell, parallelism can be achieved by running one of the commands (or both) in the background, using the `&` operator. Can you add your script (or relevant parts, if it is too long) to your question, and point out at which point you need to delete the data-migration pod in parallel?